# Rendering Order In React

Tags: reactjs, components, lifecycle

I am trying to understand the rendering order of Methods in React. I have a "persons" class and I iterate an array inside it calling a child component called "person".

My Persons.js in below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person/Person';


class Persons extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('[Persons.js] inside constructor',props);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log('[Persons.js] inside componentWillMount()');
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('[Persons.js] inside componentDidMount()');
    }

    render(){
        console.log('[Persons.js] inside render())');
        return(
            this.props.persons.map((person,index)=>{
                return(
                    <Person click={() => this.props.clicked(index)} name={person.name} age={person.age} change={ (event) => this.props.changed(event,index)} key={person.id}/>
                );
              })
        );
    }
}

export default Persons;
```

My Person.js is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Person.css'

class Person extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('[Person.js] inside constructor',props);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log('[Person.js] inside componentWillMount()');
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('[Person.js] inside componentDidMount()');
    }

    render(){
        console.log('[Person.js] inside render()');
        return(
            <div className={classes.Person}>
                <p onClick={this.props.click}>I'm {this.props.name} and {this.props.age} years old.</p>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.change} value={this.props.name}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Person;
```

All I want to know is, why doesn't it invoke componentDidMount after render method of Person.js file? Instead, it invokes 4 times after finish iterating.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6BYg.png)

Any idea?

Comment: Mounting is when it gets put into the actual DOM. So initially, the render function builds the DOM virtually, which includes rendering each of those children 1 by 1. Then, when it's finished and the new DOM is ready to be displayed, it's mounted in its entirety (which means mounting those 4 children, at the same time). Mounting is done after _everything_ has been rendered and the DOM tree is ready for display.

Comment: Does it push all the child elements to the real dom and then the parent?

Comment: No, for each render (and re-render) the new DOM is built in its entirety in memory, and once everything has been calculated, the entire tree is pushed to the real DOM in one go and the new DOM is drawn in the browser. Drawing stuff in the browser is the slowest part, so when changing the real DOM it's best to do it all in one go to prevent re-drawing. Hence why only after _everything_ has finished rendering virtually are the changes pushed to the real DOM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: No worries. Also, in my previous comment I meant "to prevent unnecessary* re-drawing"